# Browser back functionality in angular js

Tags: angularjs

How to make the browser back functionality in angular? If the browser back button is clicked, the previous state data remain selected in the old page.

Please share your idea.

Comment: Im confused, do you want the state data to persist between pages or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I keep the model value when click browser back button with angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859368/can-i-keep-the-model-value-when-click-browser-back-button-with-angularjs)

Comment: Yes Daniel, i need the state data to be persist between the page.can you please share some code for reference.