# Access service outside of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to hide and show menu items based on a value stored inside of a service. It's a qnd Session-Service that logs the user in, based on an accessToken stored in `$cookies.accessToken`:

```
app.service('Session', function ($cookies, $location) {
  var Session = {
    isLoggedIn: !! $cookies.accessToken,
    accessToken: $cookies.accessToken,

    login: function (token, redirectTo) {
      this.accessToken = token;
      this.isLoggedIn = true;

      if (redirectTo) {
        $location.path(redirectTo);
      }
    },
    logout: function () {
      this.accessToken = false;
      this.isLoggedIn = false;
    }
  };

  if (Session.accessToken) {
    Session.login(Session.accessToken)
  }

  return Session;
});
```

I currently have 3 controllers and use the `ngView` directive to show the appropriate partials. However, as you can imagine, I don't want either the "log out" or the "auth" link to show up:

```
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#/public">public</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/logout">log out</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/auth">auth</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>
```

I tried `ng-hide="Session.isLoggedIn"` but that didn't work out. So what's the right way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you access the Session service within every controller?

Comment: Sure, I can. Not so sure what you're driving at…

Comment: If you store the isLoggedIn as a scope's property ngHide should work as expected.

Comment: Tried that… but as expected the scope per controller is inside the `<div ng-view>[…]</div>`. So I can't access scope-properties outside of it.

Comment: Okay maybe I don't get your problem. I would inject the service in the controller that handles the view (than you should be able to access it), store whether there the user is logged in or not and display the appropriate navigation options. :)

Comment: The Navigation is outside of the controller's scope, that's the problem :/

Comment: Then put a controller on your navigation... See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14206567/259038).

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller Head -> Table. Thanks! (Could you rephrase this as an answer so that I can mark it as such?)