# AngularJS getting user info and storing for later use

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I'm trying to get Angular JS ng-repeat to store information from users, so they can use it to log in with later. Am I doing this right?

**.html**

```
<div id='div' ng-controller="usersCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in users">
      {{ x.username + ", " + x.password}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/users.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

**angular.js**

```
app.controller('usersCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.users = [
    {username: 'Regie', password: 'Tano'},
    {username: 'Greg', password: 'Mayer'},
    {username: 'Jacob', password: 'Minshall'},
    {username: 'Bank', password: 'Chaiwong'}
  ]
})
```

Comment: You could create `UserService` to share data between application..

Comment: So basically you want to store usernames and passwords within your JS file, and then render them on the page so anyone can see them?

Comment: I want to store user info that will be later used to log into the app

Comment: Possbile duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206492/how-do-i-store-a-current-user-context-in-angular

Answer (score 2):

You should create Service to do it

```
     app.factory('myService', function() {
 var savedData = {};
 return {
  set: set,
  get: get
 }
 function set(data) {
     savedData['user']  = data
 }
 function get() {
  return savedData;
 }
```

Here is plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/jfoDRcOSl0hP8ErVlZ3u?p=preview